# Hyperterminal quick question

Tags: serial-port, hyperterminal

I need some help on using this pre-historic application: hyperterminal.
I need to send some commands to a COM port. Im doing this: new connection > give connection a name and an icon > select COM3 port and 115200kbaud > OK > type some text and press ENTER.

I have a loop-back circuit so I expect to receive what I type. However when I press enter and didn't see nothing.

Any suggestions?

For "debuging my skills" with hyperterminal Im using a C# app I made some time ago which also sends and receives dada from COM ports. With this application I have no problems so I guess Im doing something wrong in hyperterminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "doing something wrong in Hyperterminal" includes clicking on the icon to launch it in the first place.

But it should be able to do this kind of loopback.  Make sure you don't have any kind of flow control enabled, and make sure you click the disconnect button on Hyperterminal before you change any settings - some earlier versions let you change settings with the port open but they didn't take effect until you did a disconnect/reconnect.

The other advice is that CR/LF are the last chars I would try and use to establish basic RS232 connectivity, as they they're both whitespace and have the most complicated handling in terminal programs (might be suppressed or injected).  Personally I always use 0x57, but that's just me...

Answer (score 1):

Have checked the "no flow control" option?  IIRC hyperterm defaults to hardware handshaking

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to deactivate flow control? I have never been able to establish a connection with activated flow control.

You should examine what configuration (bps, word size, flow control, parity...) you use in your c# - application, and try to transfer this to hyperterminal.